# Car shaking and mysterious brown goo

Tags: engine, toyota, corolla, shaking

I have a Toyota Corolla 2013. After starting my car, it started shaking quite a bit for 5-10 seconds. It stopped afterwards, and I turned it off. I turned it on again and it worked perfectly, however the “Check Engine” and “Trac Off” lights came on. I’ve driven about 400 km since then without any problems, but the lights are still on (the traction button doesn’t turn it off).

I opened the hood, and noticed a layer of thick brown goo covering some parts (pics [image: one], [image: two], [image: three]). The hood itself is pretty clean. I’m not sure if it has anything to do with the shaking, since I’m not sure if the goo appeared before that or after since I hadn’t looked under the hood in a while.

There’s also some sort of cardboard or wood that seems damaged (red circle), not sure if that’s related. There’s no leak on the pavement, and no smoke.

Any idea what it could be? I’m thinking about buying an error reader to get the error code. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Getting the codes read is going to go a long way to getting your question answered.

Comment: Or go to a qualified mechanic or a live friend who knows cars. Heavy shaking could be a misfire. The brown goo, who knows? Did you buy this recently? Have it serviced recently? Could be many things. An auto store like Advanced/AutoZone/OReilly may do a code check for free.

Comment: It appears to be rust. Read the codes first.